# NLog outputting all fields in `message` property

Tags: redis, kibana, nlog

I'm using NLog with a Redis target. In an older version all of the attributes in my layout used to appear as 1st class data-items when viewing in Kibana.

Since upgrading to the latest version they all appear as a JSON encoded string value against a single data-item named `message`.

I've tried specifying a JsonLayout for the `message` value but it has made no difference

```
<targets async="true">
  <target xsi:type="FallbackGroup" name="fallbacklogger" returnToFirstOnSuccess="true">
    <target xsi:type="Redis" name="RedisLog" appName="${appName}" environmentKey="EnvironmentName" connectionStringKey="LoggingRedisConnectionString" includeAllProperties="true" keySettingsKey="LoggingRedisKey">
      <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">

        <attribute name="message" encode="false">
          <layout type="JsonLayout" includeAllProperties="true" includeMdlc="true"></layout>
        </attribute>

      </layout>
    </target>
  </target>
</targets>
```

How do I get these back to first class data-items in Kibana so that I can click the `Filter` button against them?

[image: Message]

Comment: Got this working after all?

Comment: Someone at work thinks they know the answer, but we cannot implement it until we update some dependent packages. I'll ask him for some info.

Comment: @Julian Answer posted

Answer (score 2):

Someone at work fixed this problem, he said he upgraded all dependencies to the latest version and then changed the following:

[image: Config file changes]